# Full load current in Transformer

Tags: transformer

If we connect Resistor, Inductor and capacitor in series on the secondary side of the transformer such that they become full load.

And then if we connect Resistor, Inductor and capacitor in parallel on the secondary side of the transformer such that they become full load.

Then would the full load current be equal or different in both cases?

Comment: are you removing the series connected components in the second scenario?

Comment: Yes there is no series component in the second case but In both cases load is full load.

Comment: If 'full load' means the transformer's full load, then if they are both drawing full load, the load currents will be equal. If it means full load for the particular components you've connected, then it matters what components you've connected.

Comment: Where’s the schematic Alex?

Comment: Neil_UK. Please write it as answer.

Comment: Andy aka. Load is added regardless of serie parallel configuration. That's why I didn't mention any schematic.